# document.body.scrollLeft does not trigger as expected in Safari on OSX Lion

Tags: javascript, safari, scroll, osx-lion, fixed

Safari does not update the `document.body.scrollLeft` when sliding a finger on Apples magic mouse or on the touchpad. It only triggers when releasing the finger. Try following example in Safari under OSX Lion. It updates as expected in other browsers but works like the swiping on iOS in Safari Lion (seems to triggers on "`touchend`").

Dragging the scrollbar makes it behave as expected. Scrolling forth and back with the touchpad or Apples magic mouse makes it behave weird.

[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Z48fv/show/)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z48fv/)

It can be solvable by moving the content into a container with `width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow-left: scroll;` but my problem is that need to get it from the `body`. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try doing `body { width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow-left: scroll; }`?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't do any difference. Check the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z48fv/1/

Comment: Oh, ok. Hopefully someone else will answer, as I don't have a Mac :(

Comment: I can confirm that your demo works on Snow Leopard with a touchpad.

Comment: I have 10.7.1 Lion and Safari 5.1 and both provided links works. `Triggered` and `Scrolled` variables are updated properly. Even if I use touchpad and even with mouse (by grabbing scrollbar). It works without releasing finger/mouse-button as well.

Comment: Hm okay. Perhaps I should have been more specific, grabbing the scrollbar and dragging does not cause a problem. I have not tested on a touchpad though so it might work there too. The problem occurs for me when I scroll with Apples "magic mouse", swiping my finger to the side.

Comment: @MarekSebera Are you sure about the touchpad? I retested it on my friends computer with Lion and touchpad - tried scrolling (not by grabbing the scrollbar) and it did not update properly.

Comment: @Septnuits yes, scrollbar, using two fingers to side is working properly in Safari on both provided links

Comment: Why not put the function dostuff on the onscroll event instead of making it an interval? That wouldn't solve the problem, I'm just wondering why you have it that way.

Comment: On my original website I have all the logic in a requestAnimationFrame-loop, regardless of if the user is scrolling or not. So yes in the jsfiddle it might seem unnecessary, but I wanted it to be as close to my production environment as possible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like Apple has fixed this now, since it now suddenly works for me without changing anything.